# Javafx Named Parameters with Quotes/Spaces from Console

Tags: java, shell, unix, javafx, console

I want to start a javafx program from console and access (named) parameters with `getParameters()`

I have my parameters saved inside a variable called `args`.

When I call `java -jar test.jar --arg1="hello world" arg2=123`, it works.
However, when I type `java -jar test.jar $args`,
the parameters are split into `--arg1="hello` and `world"`

[image]

How would I be able to keep the named arguments as "arg1" -> "hello world"?

[image]

Comment: How do you valorize `args` ?

Comment: args=$(<arguments_file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this java example for test :

```
public class Echo extends Application {
   
   /*
    * (non-Javadoc)
    * @see javafx.application.Application#start(javafx.stage.Stage)
    */
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      
      Parameters params = getParameters();
      System.out.println("\nRaw");
      params.getRaw().forEach(e -> {
         System.out.println(e);
      });
      
      System.out.println("\nNamed");
      params.getNamed().keySet().forEach(key -> {
         System.out.println("key : " + key + " / value : " + params.getNamed().get(key));
      });
      
      System.out.println("\nUnnamed");
      params.getUnnamed().forEach(unnamed -> {
         System.out.println(unnamed);
      });
      
      Platform.exit();
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
   }
   
}
```

It actually works well on Windows.

```
D:\Profiles\PagboStack\Desktop           
λ set args=--arg1="Hello World" arg2=123 
                                        
D:\Profiles\PagboStack\Desktop           
λ echo %args%                            
--arg1="Hello World" arg2=123            
                                        
D:\Profiles\PagboStack\Desktop           
λ java -jar Echo.jar %args%              
                                        
Raw                                      
--arg1=Hello World                       
arg2=123                                 
                                        
Named                                    
key : arg1 / value : Hello World         
                                        
Unnamed                                  
arg2=123
```

But it is more complicated with Unix. I succeeded thanks to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/416583).
**Note that the link provides other solutions you may consider according to your needs.**

```
[13/06/2018 14:59.32]  /drives/d/profiles/pagbo/Desktop
[pagbo.stack] ➤ export args='--arg1="Hello World"|arg2=123'
                                 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[13/06/2018 15:05.04]  /drives/d/profiles/pabgo/Desktop
[pagbo.stack] ➤ IFS='|'
                                 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[13/06/2018 15:05.07]  /drives/d/profiles/pagbo/Desktop
[pagbo.stack] ➤ "$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java.exe -jar Echo.jar $args

Raw
--arg1="Hello World"
arg2=123

Named
key : arg1 / value : "Hello World"

Unnamed
arg2=123
```

The point here is to change the internal field separator (IFS) which is by default space.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle's Command Line Arguments Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) states that args should have the value of "hello world" enclosed within quotation marks in order to be considered a single argument. 
Try editing your arguments_file to have them in quotes.

Comment: I tried these 3 methods: `--arg1="hello world"`, `--"arg1=hello world"` and `"--arg1=hello world"`. All three lead to the same result as shown in the picture above, except with the orange " (\") in different places.  
Note, however, that if I do not access a console variable at all, but type the commands in manually, it works. `java -jar test.jar --arg1="hello world"`
But I wish to read the arguments from a file into a variable, and use them.

Comment: @user3193260 I tried with "--arg1=hello world" "arg2=123" in the program arguments and it worked.

Comment: @Pagbo did you try storing  "--arg1=hello world" "arg2=123" into a console variable/file and using that? Does that still work? If yes, please copy and paste the commands you used.